# Definir cor do texto do botão programaticamente

Tags: java, android

Tenho um botão criado na minha classe `Main` via código, isto é, programaticamente. Veja:

```
Button btnJonSnow = new Button(this);
btnJonSnow.setText("Jon Snow");
```

Como posso definir a cor do texto do botão programaticamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para definir uma cor para o texto do botão é necessário usar o atributo `setTextColor()`. Logo para resgatar a cor podes usar o método estático `getColor()` da classe pública [ContextCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html). Veja um exemplo:

```
Button btnJonSnow = new Button(this);
btnJonSnow.setText("Jon Snow");
btnJonSnow.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorAccent));
```